# How to run django rest project as windows service

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to run Django-Rest application as a windows service. Just to keep it simple. i want to know a way to deploy my Django-Rest application in a windows server and run in the background.  Can anyone please let me know if they have come across this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Django-Rest application is the instance of Django. So, you need to run Django on your Windows server first (installing all dependencies and so on). The you can try Apache